# Next js and firebase authentication login page problem

Tags: firebase-authentication, next.js

I'm using nextjs and having a problem with firebase authentication. When I log in it, I the session is stored at IndexedDB (I guess), and then I have a context that has an useEffect with the method onAuthStateChanged, which updates the user when it is changed.
Let's say I have a /login and a /dashboard (private page), when the login occurs, it should send me to /dashboard. That works fine. The problem comes when I try to go to /login (by typing the link in browser, thus refreshing) **without** logging off, which should send me back to /dashboard again. Instead of making the component be blank till the data is fetched, it loads the login page, **only then** renders the dashboard again.

```
  const Dashboard = dynamic(() => import('../pages/dashboard'))

  const router = useRouter()
  const { signIn, user } = useAuth()
  const { addToast } = useToast()
  const formRef = useRef<FormHandles>(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(user)
    if (!user) return
    router.replace('/login', '/dashboard', { shallow: true })
  }, [user])
```

I use dynamic to render the page conditionally

```
      return (
        <>
          {user ? (
            <Dashboard />
          ) : (
            <>
              <Head>
                <title>Login</title>
              </Head>
              <Container>
                <Content>
                  <img src={Logo} width={245} alt="Imobiliária Predial Primus" />

                  <Form ref={formRef} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <h1>Faça seu login</h1>

                    <Input name="email" placeholder="E-mail" />
                    <Input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Senha" />

                    <Button type="submit">Entrar</Button>

                    <a href="#"> Esqueci minha senha</a>
                  </Form>
                </Content>

                <Background />
              </Container>
            </>
          )}
        </>
      )
```

As you can see, "user" is what conditionally renders the page, but since it comes null everytime the page loads, this problem occur.

This is the Auth.tsx context, which I wrap around the app.

```
    import React, {
      createContext,
      useCallback,
      useContext,
      useState,
      useEffect
    } from 'react'
    import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

    // Firebase
    import { auth } from '../config/firebase'
    import { User } from '../interfaces'

    interface SignInCredentials {
      email: string
      password: string
    }

    interface AuthContextData {
      user: User
      signIn(credentials: SignInCredentials): Promise<void>
      signOut(): void
    }

    const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextData>({} as AuthContextData)

    const AuthProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
      const router = useRouter()
      const [user, setUser] = useState(auth.currentUser)

      useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
          console.log('user', user)
          setUser(user)

          if (!user) {
            router.push('/login')
          }
        })
        return () => {
          unsubscribe()
        }
      }, [])

      const signIn = useCallback(async (data: SignInCredentials) => {
        await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(data.email, data.password)
      }, [])

      const signOut = useCallback(() => {
        auth.signOut()
        router.push('/login')
      }, [])

      return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, signIn, signOut }}>
          {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
      )
    }

    function useAuth(): AuthContextData {
      const context = useContext(AuthContext)

      if (!context) {
        throw new Error('useAuth must be used within an AuthProvider')
      }

      return context
    }

    export { AuthProvider, useAuth }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed utilizing Cookies and NextPage, with getServerSideProps